# First Questions not showing first questions on literature

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On Literature, [this user](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/763/jonathan-decarlo) just posted [their first question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/how-did-the-grandfather-meet-his-fate-in-the-tigers-wife) on literature, but it doesn't show up under the Review First Questions tab under Review.

Answer (score 3):

It was posted 2 hours ago; it has likely been reviewed by 2 users already (and thus doesn't show up anymore).